# Docker: mount path must be absolute when using volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-cli

I am on a windows host and using git bash.
My goal is to create an alias for **Jekyll** on my git bash: run the docker image instead of installing all the dependencies. I also want to store the "gems" in a local docker volume.

I would like to use the image `jekyll/jekyll:stable` and the image has a readme [here](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/README.md).

This is the alias that I have in my aliases.sh:
`alias jekyll='winpty docker run --rm --volume=$PWD:/srv/jekyll --mount type=volume,src=gems,dst=/usr/gem,volume-driver=local -it jekyll/jekyll:stable'`

Issuing `jekyll` results in:
`docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/gem' mount path must be absolute. See 'docker run --help'.`

I don't understand: I am trying to mount a **volume**, not a bind mount. I have also tried to use the more simplistic "-v" syntax, same result. Is my docker trying to mount ***gems*** as a (directory) bind mount?

I also tried to debug this with bash `set -x`, the actual command issued was `winpty docker run --rm --volume=/h/:/srv/jekyll --mount type=volume,src=gems,dst=/usr/gem,volume-driver=local -it jekyll/jekyll:stable` which looks OK.

UPDATE: It seems that perhaps the `/usr` destination (in container) is being translated as `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/gem` which is wrong... I'd need to somehow insert a **literal** `/usr/` in my command.